# Mongoose not creating MongoDB, even though working previous times

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've used Mongoose for a couple of my projects, but once I attempted to create the Database this time with Mongoose, it shares no errors but does not create the intended "user" database.

As an example,

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then(()=>{
        console.log("mongoose");
    })
    .catch(e=>{
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Additionally, I tried creating previous models with previous databases and tried creating new DBs with previous working nodejs files, no luck.

If anyone has had a similar issue or has any helps to take care of this issue, much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB will not create the database or collection until you insert a document, create an index, or explicitly call the `create` database command.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you forgot two things in the configuration.

1. You forgot the: useCreateIndex: true
2. useFindAndModify: false

So the final code should look like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const dbConnection = async() => {

    try {
        
        await mongoose.connect( YourConnectionLink, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false
        });

        console.log('Database online!!');

    } catch (error) {
        
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error('Error');

    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work out, I think it might be a MongoDB problem because my previous code boilerplate for connecting/creating new DBs has worked until now.

Comment: Maybe is a problem with the Network configuration in Mongo Altas, does you allowed the access from any ip?