# Not showing database in mongodb compass

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-web-server

**I am trying to connect my node.js server to the mongo database. I have created a database name "breathe_in_db" in dealer-database.js file and When i try to run the server It says that i have successfully connected to the database on terminal however, no any database named "breathe_in_db" is showing on the mongodb compass.**

index.js

```
//import required dependencies
const express = require('express');
const profiledb = require('./db/dealer-database');


//Initialising express app
const app = express();


//Assigning port 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//enable json in request 
app.use(express.json())


//Connecting to all essential databases before firing up the API

Promise.all([profiledb.ConnectToDb()])
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to All Databases")
        registerRoutesAndStartListening();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));


module.exports = app;
```

dealer-database.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const DB_NAME = 'breathe_in_db';

const DEFAULT_CONN_STRING = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${ DB_NAME }`

// A Promise to connect TO MongoDB
const ConnectToDb = (connectionString = DEFAULT_CONN_STRING) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mongoose.connect(connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
            (err) => {
                if (err)
                    return reject(err)
                return resolve();
            })
    })
}


module.exports = { ConnectToDb };
```

Comment: Please check the connection string you are using to connect with Compass. Are you connecting to the correct cluster, where the created database resides?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67815880/2282634